# Cocos2d - removeChild by location

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, removechild

I have a number on CCSprites on screen which have CCNodes placed upon them, and added as children. How can I remove the CCNode child based on touch location (or touched sprite location)?

I have attempted creating a custom method (see below) but am unsure how to fill it in.

```
 -(void)removeChild:(CCNode*)node location:(CGPoint)location cleanup:(BOOL)cleanup;
```

Is it possible to specify location with the built in method?

```
[self removeChild:(CCNode *)[node at location] cleanup:(BOOL)cleanup]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get local rect of your sprite by sending `boundingBox` message. Then just test your touch position with `CGRectContainsPoint` function. The only thing you should remember, that you need convert your coordinates(for example, if your sprites are children of some node, then their rects will be relative to it's (0.f, 0.f) coordinate, not to the scene (0.f, 0.f)). Also you should convert your touch location with sending `convertToGL:` message to `CCDirector` shared instance.

Comment: Thanks for the info Morion. I currently have a CCSprite "_selectedSprite", which represents the touched sprite, using a similar set up to the one you mentioned. Unfortunately I was unable to remove a child based on that location. To solve my problem what I have done instead is used the in built "removeChildByTag" function, and tagged all the nodes which are built on the sprites. I had to manually state each and every sprite created, but the process works.